# Add image to rectangle array - C#

Tags: c#, class, multidimensional-array, rectangles, drawimage

I've got the following code and wanted to know whether there was a way for me to assign the `brickImage` property to the array featured in my code. If so, how do I achieve this? I basically want to create an array of bricks to be displayed in multiple rows etc.

```
public class Brick
    {
        private int x, y, width, height;
        private Image brickImage;
        private Rectangle brickRec;
        private Rectangle[] brickRecs;

        public Rectangle BrickRec
        {
            get { return brickRec; }
        }


        public Brick()
        {
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            width = 60;
            height = 20;


            brickImage = Breakout.Properties.Resources.brick_fw;

            brickRec = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

            Rectangle[] brickRecs =
            {
                new Rectangle(0, 0, 60, 20),
                new Rectangle(0, 0, 121, 20),
                new Rectangle(0, 0, 242, 20)

            };

        }


        public void drawBrick(Graphics paper)
        {
            paper.DrawImage(brickImage, brickRec);

            //paper.DrawImage(brickImage, brickRecs);
        }

    }
```

Comment: "to the array featured in my code" -- to which array featured in your code? The one in the `Brick` class you showed here? It's not even clear why that class _has_ a `Rectangle[]`, never mind what it would mean for there to be an instance of `Image` in it. If you have an array of `Brick` objects somewhere else, why not just pass in the reference to the `Image` you want for that `Brick` object, to allow different images to be used for different `Brick` objects?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to attach an image to a rectangle simply **create your own class**:

```
public class MyBrick
{
   public Image Image {get; set;}
   public Point[] Locations {get; set;}
}
```

then add this somewhere in your code

```
MyBrick[] brickRecs  = 
{
   new MyBrick()
   {
       Locations = 
       {
          new Point(60, 20),
          new Point(10, 10),
          //....
       },
       Image = ... // ADD IMAGE REFERENCE HERE
   },

   new MyBrick()
   {
       Locations = 
       {
          new Point(90, 90),
          new Point(5, 5),
          //....
       },
       Image = ... 
   },
};
```

Comment: This may well result in a __great__ waste of resources. Instead, only references should be stored, maybe he could use an `ImageList` and only store a key or an index! This is the best way if all images have the same size. Otherwise a `List<Bitmap>` would help..

Comment: @Boris, tell us a little more: How many different brick images and how many different image sizes will you have?

Comment: List<Bitmap>??? **do you know how much a single Bitmap object weights?** i agree that refernces are better - but that was only a general demonstration

Comment: @TaW Sizes of the bricks will be the same, regards the images, I was hoping to use 3-4 different ones within the array (to represent different coloured bricks) and finally display the bricks in multiple rows with the coloured bricks to be placed in random locations within the array.

Comment: In that list each Bitmap would be stored only once. All bricks that use it would only refer to its index. In fact you can modify your code a little and use a getter that points into the List. Or as it stands now into the ImageList..

Comment: @Boris: In that case load the images into an `ImageList`. (Do set its properties first, ie size and colordepth!!). Then you can use the code in the answer adding/replacong an `int index` which points into the ImageList. Then simply refer to each Image like this: `Image img = imageList1.Images[index];`

Comment: I'm struggling creating the class, for some reason I'm getting errors?

Comment: my bad.. i forgot the class keyword.. it will work now as excpected

Comment: Where it says `// ADD IMAGE REFERENCE HERE` Does that mean I have to use the following code? : `Image = Breakout.Properties.Resources.brick_fw;`

Comment: I tried the code, here's what I got: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c7d4fba0ef52822fc5cc However, I get a massive red X across the form when I try and compile the code. The error is when I try and use the function `drawBrick`

Comment: brickImage is nuul and that is why you get the error.. you should initialize it or use Breakout.Properties.Resources.brick_fw instead